# api data does not show up on screen, just in console

Tags: java, ios, api, flutter, dart

what I'm trying to do is display the API data (book title and review url) on a card inside a flutter app. Its the new york times API and I want to show up all stephen king book reviews. It all gets printed into the console, but it doesn't happen anything on screen. When I click on the button, it only gets printed, but I want the data to show up in a Card on screen. Please help, here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//outsource the class BookReview for OOP
class BookReview extends StatefulWidget {
  static const apiKey = 'jH8F2A1FCudwGV8udVAU4YSLLEr8vqxT';
  static const apiURL =
      'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=Stephen+King&api-key=$apiKey';

  @override
  _BookReviewState createState() => _BookReviewState();
}

class _BookReviewState extends State<BookReview> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getBookData();
  }

  Card bookCard;

  var bookNum = List.generate(66, (i) => i);

  Future<Card> getBookData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(BookReview.apiURL);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      for (int book in bookNum) {
        String bookTitle = decodedData['results'][book]['book_title'];
        String reviewURL = decodedData['results'][book]['url'];

        print(bookTitle + ' ' + reviewURL);
      }

      return Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw ('there is an error with the status code');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stephen King NYT Reviews'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final Card tmpBookCard = await getBookData();
              setState(() {
                bookCard = tmpBookCard;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.picture_as_pdf,
              size: 50.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use your **bookCard** widget in your build function. For example you should use your bookCard in top of FlatButton Widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stephen King NYT Reviews'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          bookCard,
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final Card tmpBookCard = await getBookData();
              setState(() {
                bookCard = tmpBookCard;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.picture_as_pdf,
              size: 50.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see where you defined your bookCard but also in **getBookData()** , you don't insert data you got into Card you return